# laravel 5 twitter api tweet not enter to db

Tags: php, api, laravel-5, twitter-oauth

I'm using  thujohn/twitter
I planed my algorithim depend on 3 types 
1 - no likes
2 - less than 200 likes
3 - more than 200 likes
the problem is where I get them then save into database (some of tweets are lost)
some other deplicated espically the last group

this is my code in homecontroller which belong to third group

```
  public function many(){
    set_time_limit(600);
   $fav =  Twitter::getUserTimeline(['count' => 1, 'format' => 'array']);
   $total = $fav[0]['user']['favourites_count'];
        $counts = ceil($total/190);
    $likes1 =  Twitter::getFavorites(['screen_name' => 'TestFavorites', 'count' => 200 , 'format' => 'array']);

         if (is_array($likes1) || is_object($likes1))
        {
                foreach ($likes1 as $value)
                {
                         $save = new Tweet();
                         $save->user_id=1;
                         $save->tweet = utf8_encode($value['text']);       
                         $save->id_str = $value['id_str'];
                         $save->save();
                }
        }


             $check = Tweet::all();

             if($check){
             for($m=0;$m<$counts;$m++){

             $last = DB::table('tweets')
                 ->latest('created_at')
                 ->first();

             $max_id = ''.$last->id_str.'';
             $second =  Twitter::getFavorites(['screen_name' => 'TestFavorites', 'count' => 200,'max_id' => ''.$last->id_str.'' , 'format' => 'array']);


             foreach($second as $items1)
             {
                 $save1 = new Tweet();
                 $save1->user_id=1;
                 $save1->tweet = utf8_encode($items1['text']);       
                 $save1->id_str = $items1['id_str'];
                 $save1->save();


}}}
}
```

Comment: no comments !! :(